# Each row of an n x n table form an arithmetic progression. Find n such that table can be transformed so that each column form arithmetic series

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, permutations

We place $ 1,\ldots,n^2$ integer numbers into an $n \times n$ table. We call this table good if each row can be permuted to form an arithmetic progression. For what value of $n$ can we transform (by permuting the numbers in each row) any such good table into a table where each column can be permuted to form an arithmetic progression?

Comment: Please contribute any thoughts even if you don’t have a full-on answer!

Comment: Not so much a thought as a few questions – where does your question come from? What do you know about it? Are there values of $n$ for which you know the answer? For which values of $n$ is it even possible to partition $1,2,\dots,n^2$ into $n$ disjoint arithmetic progressions, each of length $n$ (other than the progressions with common difference one, and those with difference $n$)?

Comment: Here is one for $n=3$ with common differences $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3$ : $\begin{pmatrix}1&3&5\\4&6&2\\7&9&8\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: By brute force, for $2 \le n \le 12$ the values for which every good table can be made "doubly good" are precisely the primes. This is certainly suggestive... But I've realised that I'm not sure whether "any such good table" should be interpreted as an existential or a universal quantifier.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Your interpretation is far more interesting and explains the complex phrasing in the question and the incomplete title.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:** I probably misread the question. Peter Taylor's comments explain why it didn't need to forbid common differences $1$ and $n$. My answer below is therefore in need of revisions.*

There is some non-trivial solution for any integer $n\ge 3$.

Write $n=k\cdot m+1$ with $k\ge 1$ and $m\ge 2$. Set the first $m$ rows in permuted arithmetic progressions with common difference $m$ and the other $n-m$ rows in permuted arithmetic progressions with common difference $1$ as follows, all columns being in permuted arithmetic progressions with common difference $n$:

$3 = 1\cdot 2+1$

$$\begin{array}{cc:cc}
1&3&5&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
4&6&\mathbf{2}&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
\hdashline
7&9&8&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_3}&\scriptstyle{_3}&\scriptstyle{_3}
\end{array}$$

$4 = 1\cdot 3+1$

$$\begin{array}{cc:ccc}
1&4&7&10&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
5&8&11&\mathbf{2}&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
9&12&\mathbf{3}&6&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
\hdashline
13&16&15&14&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_4}&\scriptstyle{_4}&\scriptstyle{_4}&\scriptstyle{_4}
\end{array}$$

$5 = 2\cdot 2+1$

$$\begin{array}{ccc:ccc}
1&3&5&7&9&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
6&8&10&\mathbf{2}&\mathbf{4}&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
\hdashline
11&13&15&12&14&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
16&18&20&17&19&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
21&23&25&22&24&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}
\end{array}$$

$5 = 1\cdot 4+1$

$$\begin{array}{cc:cccc}
1&5&9&13&17&\;\scriptstyle{^4}\\
6&10&14&18&\mathbf{2}&\;\scriptstyle{^4}\\
11&15&19&\mathbf{3}&7&\;\scriptstyle{^4}\\
16&20&\mathbf{4}&8&12&\;\scriptstyle{^4}\\
\hdashline
21&25&24&23&22&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}&\scriptstyle{_5}
\end{array}$$

$6 = 1\cdot 5+1$

$$\begin{array}{cc:ccccc}
1&6&11&16&21&26&\;\scriptstyle{^5}\\
7&12&17&22&27&\mathbf{2}&\;\scriptstyle{^5}\\
13&18&23&28&\mathbf{3}&8&\;\scriptstyle{^5}\\
19&24&29&\mathbf{4}&9&14&\;\scriptstyle{^5}\\
25&30&\mathbf{5}&10&15&20&\;\scriptstyle{^5}\\
\hdashline
31&36&35&34&33&32&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_6}&\scriptstyle{_6}&\scriptstyle{_6}&\scriptstyle{_6}&\scriptstyle{_6}&\scriptstyle{_6}
\end{array}$$

$7 = 3\cdot 2+1$

$$\begin{array}{cccc:ccc}
1&3&5&7&9&11&13&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
8&10&12&14&\mathbf{2}&\mathbf{4}&\mathbf{6}&\;\scriptstyle{^2}\\
\hdashline
15&17&19&21&16&18&20&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
22&24&26&28&23&25&27&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
29&31&33&35&30&32&34&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
36&38&40&42&37&39&41&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
43&45&47&49&44&46&48&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}
\end{array}$$

$7 = 2\cdot 3+1$

$$\begin{array}{ccc:cccc}
1&4&7&10&13&16&19&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
8&11&14&17&20&\mathbf{2}&\mathbf{5}&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
15&18&21&\mathbf{3}&\mathbf{6}&9&12&\;\scriptstyle{^3}\\
\hdashline
22&25&28&24&27&23&26&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
29&32&35&31&34&30&33&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
36&39&42&38&41&37&40&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
43&46&49&45&48&44&47&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}
\end{array}$$

$7 = 1\cdot 6+1$

$$\begin{array}{cc:ccccc}
1&7&13&19&25&31&37&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
8&14&20&26&32&38&\mathbf{2}&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
15&21&27&33&39&\mathbf{3}&9&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
22&28&34&40&\mathbf{4}&10&16&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
29&35&41&\mathbf{5}&11&17&23&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
36&42&\mathbf{6}&12&18&24&30&\;\scriptstyle{^6}\\
\hdashline
43&49&48&47&46&45&44&\;\scriptstyle{^1}\\
\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}&\scriptstyle{_7}
\end{array}$$

$\vdots$

There is a natural question to ask then:

> Is there any solution that don't use any $1$ and $n$ at all as common differences ?

Comment: The answer to your follow-up question is: certainly not for $n \le 9$. There are solutions which don't use $1$ (e.g. $[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]$) or which don't use $n$ (I've only found $[1,1,1,3]$).

Comment: But actually this is all addressing a slightly different question to the one asked, which is about the existence of tables where each row is an a.p. but row permutation **doesn't** create columns which can be permuted to a.p.s.

Comment: Actually, on further rereading, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Further refining the analysis of the common differences, it seems that the table $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ is exceptional as the only table where the (wlog) columns don't all have common difference $n$.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:** I added the prime case at the beginning, fully answering the question in agreement with Peter Taylor's observation.*

It is exactly when $n$ is prime.

## Proof of the prime case

Consider any good $n\times n$ table with $n=p$ prime.

Let $d_i$ be the common difference of the arithmetic progression in row $i=1, 2, \dots, p$.

*Lemma: either all $d_i=p$ or no $d_i=p$.*

*Proof:* Assume $d_i=p$ and $d_j=r\ne p$ for some $i, j$. The numbers on row $i$ span a set
$$S_i=\{x, x+p, x+2p, \dots, x+(p-1)p\}$$
for some $x$ in $\{1, 2, \dots, p\}$ and the numbers on row $j$ span a set
$$S_j=\{y, y+r, y+2r, \dots, y+(p-1)r\}$$
for some $y$ in $\{1, 2, \dots, p^2\}$. Now $r =1, 2, \dots, p-1$ or $p+1$ but no more in order to keep the largest element in $S_j$ no bigger than $p^2$. Therefore $\gcd(r,p)=1$ and $S_j\mod p$ spans all of $\{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}\mod p$. In particular $z\equiv x\mod p$ for some $z$ in $S_j$. In other  words $z=x+kp$ for some $z$ in $S_j$ and some integer $k$. Since $1\le z\le n^2$, this $x+kp$ must be in $S_i$ as well. This is a contradiction, the rows beeing assumed to be disjoint. *QED*

Now, on one hand, if all $d_i=p$, the only possible $p$ arithmetic progressions on the rows are exactly those on the rows of
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&1+p&1+2p&\dots&1+(p-1)p\\
2&2+p&2+2p&\dots&2+(p-1)p\\
3&3+p&3+2p&\dots&3+(p-1)p\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p&p+p&p+2p&\dots&p+(p-1)p
\end{array}
$$
albeit possibly in another order of rows and another order of elements within each row. This shows our initial $n\times n$ table is doubly good.

On the other hand, if no $d_i=n$, then $\gcd(d_i,p)=1$ as in the lemma, hence the $p$ numbers on any row $i$ span $\{1, 2, \dots, p\}\mod p$ exactly. Now permute the elements on row $i$ so that they appear in that order $\mod p$. Doing it on every row, the table is then put in a state where all elements in any column $j$ are congruent to $j\mod p$. This implies column $j$ is exactly $j,$ $j+p,$ $j+2p,$ $\dots,$ $j+(p-1)p$, possibly in some other order. For any $j=1, 2, \dots, p$. And we are done with the prime case!

## Proof of the composite case

With Peter Taylor insight, for any composite $n=a\cdot b$ with $a,b \ge 2$, here is some $n\times n$ table with rows in arithmetic progressions that fails to be "doubly good". Failing means there is no choice of independant horizontal permutations of the elements of each rows which, after they all are applied and we look at the resulting table, display columns as (possibly disordered) arithmetic progressions of $n$ elements.

For $n=6=2\cdot 3$ the proposed table is
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
(1)&\underline{4}&7&10&13&16\\
2&5&(8)&11&\underline{14}&17\\
3&6&\underline{9}&12&(15)&18\\
\hdashline
\underline{19}&(22)&25&28&31&34\\
20&23&26&\underline{(29)}&32&35\\
21&\underline{24}&27&30&33&(36)
\end{array}$$
while $n=6=3\cdot 2$ will also work with the alternate table
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
(1)&\underline{3}&5&7&9&11\\
2&4&6&\underline{(8)}&10&12\\
\hdashline
\underline{13}&(15)&17&19&21&23\\
14&16&\underline{18}&20&(22)&24\\
\hdashline
25&27&(29)&31&33&35\\
26&\underline{28}&30&32&34&(36)
\end{array}$$

I have surrounded with parenthesis the only elements that may appear in the resulting column of $1$ if that column were to show a (possibly disordered) arithmetic progression of $n$ elements.

And underlined those for the column of $1+b$. The two columns are colliding in our two examples, preventing the tables to be "doubly good". Sometimes we cannot event get the second column right on its own, as $23$ is not avalaible on its proper row in the second table above.

I don't know if some collision can always be worked out between the two first columns in the general composite case. I give another general argument below involving the third column to prove the impossibility.

More generally set the rows $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_n$ as the following arithmetic progressions with common difference $b$
$$\begin{array}{rl}
R_1 &= \{1, 1+b, 1+2b, \dots, 1+(n-1)b\}\\
R_2 &= R_1 + 1\\
\vdots\\
R_b &= R_1 + b-1 =\{b, 2b, 3b, \dots, nb\}\\
\hdashline
R_{b+1} &= R_1 + nb\\
\vdots\\
R_{ib+j+1} &= R_1 + nib+j\quad\forall i=0, 1, \dots, a-1, \forall j=0, 1, \dots, b-1\\
\vdots\\
R_n&=R_{(a-1)b+(b-1)+1} = R_1+n(a-1)b+b-1\\
&= \{n(a-1)b+b, n(a-1)b+2b, \dots, n(a-1)b+nb\}
\end{array}$$
where the very last term is indeed $n^2$.

### Getting the column with $1$ right

Looking for horizontal permutations that might yield columns in permuted arithmetic progressions, which element $1+nb+kb = 1+(n+k)b$ in $R_{b+1}$ might go in the same column as $1$, for some $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$?

We would need $b-1$ elements in the intermediate rows $R_2, \dots,R_b$ to go in that column as well. And they would need to be in arithmetic progression together with $1$ and our choice of $1+(n+k)b$. Since they would be greater than $1$ and smaller than $1+(n+k)b$ by construction of those intermediate rows, they can only be $1+(n+k), 1+(n+k)2, \dots, 1+(n+k)(b-1)$ (in $R_2, R_3, \dots, R_b$ although not necessarily in that order).

Now $k=0$ isn't allowed because $1+(n+k)=1+ab$ would then be in $R_1$ and not in some intermediate row as assumed.

And $k\ge 2$ isn't allowed because the common difference of the column under scrutiny is necessarily $(n+k)$, making its greatest element be $1+(n+k)(n-1) = n^2+(k-1)(n-1) > n^2$, out of bound.

Therefore the only choice for an element in $R_{b+1}$ is with $k=1$ and the final column with $1$ must show an arithmetic progression of common difference $n+1$ and have elements $1+i(n+1)$ for $i=0, 1, \dots, n-1$. By congruence $\mod b$ we can even say every $1+i(n+1)$ is in row $R_{i+1}$.

### Getting the column with $1+b$ right

Which element $1+(n+k)b$ in $R_{b+1}$ might go in the same column as $1+b$, for some $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$?

$k=1$ is already taken by the column of $1$.
$k=2$ would make an arithmetic progression of common difference $n+1$, shifting the one found for $1$, but whose last element $1+b+(n-1)(n+1)$ would be out of bound.
$k\ge 3$ would be even more out of bound.
We are only left with $k=0$ for that column.

Note that the 2nd column needs to go through that element $1+nb$ in $R_{b+1}$ to get any chance to show an arithmetic progression. It may not even be right or avoid another collision with the first column. For example for the special case $n=4=2\cdot 2$, $6$ would happen to be needed for the two columns at the same time, so that our special $4\times 4$ table cannot be doubly good at all, without any need to inspect a third column as we are going to do in the general case.

### Getting no column with $1+2b$ right

Here $k=3$ and $k\ge 4$ would similarly go out of bound.
We are only left with $k=2$, but the resulting arithemtic progression would start with $1+2b$, go through $1+(n+2)b = 1+2b+nb$ on row $R_{b+1}$, with $b-1$ intermediate elements that can then only be $1+2b+n,$ $1+2b+2n,$ $\dots,$ $1+2b+(b-1)n$. But the first of them $1+2b+n=1+(a+2)b$ is also in row $R_1$, if $a+2\le n-1$, in other words $3\le a(b-1)$. This happens as soon as $a\ge 3$ or $b\ge 3$.

This proves the claim that for any composite $n = a\cdot b$, with our table there is no way to get the three columns with $1, 1+b, 1+2b$ respectively be in arithmetic progressions.

That's it.